# Lista de perguntas similares sobrepõe footer quando muito grande

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design

Ao postar uma pergunta, a lista de "Perguntas similares" pode crescer a ponto de subrepor o *footer* quando rolo até o fim da página. Ela deveria parar de acompanhar o rolamento antes de isso acontecer.

[image]

O mesmo acontece em outros sites do SE, então pode ser que seja bydesign. No entanto aqui no META o fundo não se mantem branco. Isso sem dúvida é um problema:

[image]

Comment: Vi acontecer ontem, mas não tive tempo de postar aqui.